# Skip Gram Negative Sampling with Logistics Regression

Tags: word2vec

Given a training sentences as follow form document:
**... lemon, a tablespoon of apricot jam a pinch ...**

> Word **apricot** choose to be target word as t with windows size 2

Training sample with both negative and positive samples looks like as follow
**Positive samples:** 
apricot tablespoon
apricot of
apricot preserves
apricot or

**Negative samples**: (1 positive sample with 2 corresponding negative samples)
apricot aardvark  apricot twelve
apricot puddle  apricot hello
apricot where  apricot dear
apricot coaxial  apricot forever
**The likelihood function (single word):**
$$log\frac{1}{1+e^{-c\cdot t}}+\sum_{i=1}^k log\frac{1}{1+e^{n_i\cdot t}}$$
1.*K* is 2 since we have 2 negative sample for each positive sample
2.*t* is a vector of words **apricot** 
3.*c* is a vector of words within the windows size such as **apricot tablespoon** in positive sample
4.$n_i$ is a vector of words in negative sample for each positive sample
**Questions:**
Here 's my questions:
**1**. How to fit the negative and positive sample into vector $c$ vector $n_i$ and vector $t$?
In deep learning version it is one hot encoding
but how about in this version?
**2**. Any workable example with small datasets?
**3**. How do I know my training result of vector t is correct? 
Since I prefer to study this method with only a very small datasets and this method need a lot of training sample and training time like a week
However my aim is to learn about this method not for the word embedding
It will be great for anyone offer help to my question I am not only asking for help but also share what I learn